# UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier Theory

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reuseidentifier

When apple developed the `UITableView` for the first iPhone they had a problem in performance when scrolling through it. Then one clever engineer discovered that the cause of this was that allocation of objects comes with a price, so he came up with a way to reuse cells.

> "Object allocation has a performance cost, especially if the allocation has to happen repeatedly over a short period—say, when the
>   user scrolls a table view. If you reuse cells instead of allocating
>   new ones, you greatly enhance table-view performance."
>
> *Source: iOS Reference Library*

To reuse a cell you use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Now, what I am wondering is, what actually happens here? Does it look in the TableView if there is a cell with that identifier and just returns that one? Well yea duh, but if it sends a reference instead of allocating and I have a table view with let's say 4 cells with the same identifier all visible. How can it multiply itself into four instances without allocating?

I want to know this because I am building a calendar type component and all the cells have the same structure only the text within changes. So if I could somehow reuse my cells instead of allocating I think I might get a better performance.

My own theory is that it allocates the four cells (simply because it has too). When a cell disappears from the screen it will be put in the TableView reuse queue. When a new cell is needed it looks in the que if a cell with the same identifier is available, it invokes `prepareForReuse` method on that cell and it removes itself from the queue.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. It has a separate reuse queue/set that is not the same as things already in the table.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` only returns a `cell` if it has been marked as ready for reuse. This is why in almost every `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you will see something like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Do something to cell

return cell;
```

In effect, enough rows will be allocated to fill the visible part of the `tableview` (plus one or two more). As `cells scroll` off screen, they are removed from the `table` and marked as ready for `reuse`. As the queue of "available cells" grows, your line that asks for a `dequeued cell` will start obtaining a `cell` to use, at which point you will not have to allocate anymore.

Comment: The 'one or two more' part is not correct. It allocated *exactly* what is needed. Give this a try and you will see.

Comment: Indeed like St3fan says if you NSLog the method where it asks for a cell you will see it only asks for the cell that are needed.

Comment: I was maybe a little hasty in the way I explained that. "What is needed" varies depending on the circumstance. As you start to scroll UITableView, more factors come into play. One example: if you scroll a long table view very quickly, it is possible to cause the table to request a cell when none are available to dequeue.

Comment: There's a surplus "[" before "[UITableViewCell alloc]".

Comment: Newly implemented `dequeue` method guarantees a cell is returned. I think this answer needs update.

Comment: is "off-screen" considered the literal screen? Or out of the bounds of the visible contentsize?

Answer (score 13):

The code for `deqeueueReusableCellsWithIdentifier:` will look something like this:

(Taken from one of my own projects where I do something similar with views/pages in a paged scroll view)

```
- (UIView*) dequeueReusablePage
{
    UIView* page = [reusablePages_ anyObject];
    if (page != nil) {
        [[page retain] autorelease];
        [reusablePages_ removeObject: page];
    }
    return page;
}
```

So it keeps a simple `NSMutableSet` with reusable objects.

When cells scroll off the screen and are not longer visible, they are put in this set.

So you start with an empty set and the set will only grow if you actually have more data to show then is visible on the screen.

Used cell scrolls off the top of the screen, is put in the set, then taken for the cell that appears at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is to use less memory. if we use 100 cells in a tableView then need to create 100 cells every time.It reduce the app functionality and may cause crash.
For that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` initialise the particular number of cells that we created and the cells will use again for further processing.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }

    ExternalClassTableViewCell *myCell = [[ExternalClassTableViewCell alloc]init];
    myCell.MyCellText.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.MyCellImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    return cell;
}
```