# How to add cell to tableview's reuse queue before 'cellForRow:'?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Creating a cell costs a lot of time and make the first scroll lagging, so I want to create a cell and add it to tableview's reuse queue before cellForRow: called.

I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in viewDidLoad, but when I scroll the table, the cell is being created again.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552343/uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-theory see this link

Comment: Why are you add this in viewDidLoad ? why not in cellForRow: ?

Comment: If in the cellForRow, there's no cell can be reused when first scroll,  tableview will create a cell and this will make scroll lagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general all drawing methods of scrollview should be kept as simple as possible to avoid lag. This means you should prepare your data/model in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear or even in previous ViewController. Your cellForRow should be as simple as set this image(s) and those text(s) - no checks, no expensive operations such as bluring, retrieving data from CoreData/Network, etc.

If you are not sure which thing exactly causes your lag, you should learn how to use [TimeProfiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html). If you feel lost in documentation, have a look this(quite outdated though) [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode).

With thus said I cannot be able to help you anymore until you post some code which we could discuss.