# UITableView reuse identifiers

Tags: ios, uitableview

Till today I thought I understood UITableView properly but that perception has changed as I have been fighting scrolling and content mismatch while scrolling issues.

I have a small table view with potentially 20-30 rows depending on user content. When I scroll (a bit faster than usual), the content gets mixed up. Some accessory views get interchanged, background colors get swapped or overwritten; sometimes even the text changes.

I use reuse identifiers for some of cells but I am not sure its even working out properly.

Issues:

1. Clearly a single reuse identifier is not cutting it in case — as the first and the last cell swap values.
2. With 3 reuse identifiers for first, last and remaining cells (contain settings), the accessory views get interchanged between some cells that contain settings, i.e. in some cases I use switch controls, in others I use an accessory detail button and there is blasphemy.
3. Even with 5 reuse identifiers for different types of content, the accessory views get mismatched with background colors of other cells.

I have been writing table views for a while and I have never encountered these issues before. So I have one simple question — When do you create reuse identifiers?

- only when the text/image content is different?
- when accessory views are same? i.e. for different accessory views create different reuse identifiers

I am completely lost on this so if you can really churn out an explanation, I would be really grateful.

EDIT: I have been working on this for the last 5 hours and have gone through a lot of literature and open/closed issues on StackOverflow. I understand what reusable cells are. The provided thread doesn't answer the very specific questions.

Here is some code:

```
// previously had 3 different types of cells; currently doing with one only
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [self cellIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[ESBasicTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)cellIdentifierForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *FirstCellId = @"First";
    static NSString *SecondCellId = @"Second";
    static NSString *ThirdCellId = @"Third";
    static NSString *ForthCellId = @"Forth";
    static NSString *FifthCellId = @"Fifth";
    static NSString *SixthCellId = @"Sixth";

    NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == kSectionFirst && indexPath.row == kRowFirst)
    {
        cellIdentifier = FirstCellId;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionFirst && indexPath.row == kRowSecond)
    {
        cellIdentifier = SecondCellId;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionSecond)
    {
        cellIdentifier = ThirdCellId;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionThird)
    {
        cellIdentifier = ForthCellId;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionSettings)
    {
        cellIdentifier = FifthCellId;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSEctionFifth)
    {
        cellIdentifier = SixthCellId;
    }

    return cellIdentifier;
}
```

The `configureCell:atIndexPath` method results in other configuration calls; one of them being configuration for settings:

```
- (void)configureCellForSettings:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case kRowNotificationSetting:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Notifications";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
            cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_notification_icon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            break;
        }
        case kRowSomeOtherSetting:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Auto";
            cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_auto_icon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

            UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [switchView setOn:...];

            cell.accessoryView = switchView;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Some meaningful text has been stripped out (unfortunately). The forth section is for the settings but this is just an example.

Edit: Here is `configureCell:atIndexPath:`

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == kSectionFirst)
    {
        // ...
        [self configureFirstCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionSecond)
    {
        // ...
        [self configureSecondCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionThird)
    {
        // add ...
        [self configureThirdCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionSettings)
    {
        // settings
        [self configureCellForSettings:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == kSectionFifth)
    {
        // delete button
        [self configureFifthCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Please note — I had to rename a lot of the code to have it on StackOverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier Theory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552343/uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-theory)

Comment: Questions are very different. Please see the update. Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so people can point out issues.

Comment: I don't mean to by trite, but it sounds like you don't actually fully understand what reusable cells are.

Comment: Clearly, I believe the same. I may not understand it 'completely' but I understand the stuff that's mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Your `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method and your `cellIdentifierForIndexPath:` don't match at all. That's a big problem. And you posted the `configureCellForSettings:atIndexPath:` method, not the `configureCell:atIndexPath:`method.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be necessary. I have updated with code for `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. It will be some work for me to post internal code for other cell configurations. :/

Comment: One big problem I see with the `configureCellForSettings:atIndexPath:` method is that you don't set/reset the exact same set of properties for all possible conditions. If you set the `accessoryView` (for example) in one situation, you need to set it (or reset it) for ALL situations. This is due to cell reuse.

Comment: I see. This was my secondary question to the answer below by Adam. I think I see what the problem is. And this basically corresponds to all properties like background color, text alignment, etc?

Comment: Correct - a given set of properties for a given cell reuse identfier must all be set or reset for all conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only marked this as a duplicate because it sounds like you are struggling with the concept of what is actually happening when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Whenever you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to get a cell, try to conceptualize that you are being returned one of the cells that you have previously generated and added content to **that has the same identifier** (which is, in fact, exactly what you are doing). The cell that is being returned thusly, may already have accessory views/images set, etc, and you may need to unset/remove these depending on your use case.

If you have several **types** of cells (where the layout/content differs dramatically) then you may need to consider using multiple reuse identifiers - a reuse identifier for each type of cell, so you can more easily reuse cells, rather than resetting all accessory views/images/etc every time you reuse a cell.

Comment: 'The cell that is being returned thusly, may already have accessory views/images set, etc, and you may need to unset/remove these depending on your use case.' So are you trying to say that I actually have to manually say — `cell.accessoryView = nil; cell.accessoryType = ...` to get it to work (again, this is just a sample question) and this might end up solving everything.

Comment: The second paragraph nailed it for me. Thank you very much.