# Bug in Deleting Row on UITableView at Multiple time delete row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Two bug in this code.

First one when i delete Row in tableview delete last row not selected row.

Second Bug is when try to delete more than one row that time will delete successfully but when reload tableview Only one row deleted. Rest row will appear again.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return result.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath];
        if (!(cell == nil)) {
              name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
              name.text = [result objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];
        }
        name.tag=indexPath.row;
            return cell;
    }
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return YES;
    }
    - (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
        [_myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath];
        if (!(cell == nil)) {
              name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
              name.text = [result objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];
        }
        name.tag=indexPath.row;
            return cell;
    }
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

            [result removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [spinner startAnimating];
            NSString *id = [profile objectForKey:@"user_id"];
            NSString *tb =tid;

            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&topiid=%@",id,tb];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myDeleteUrl"]];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody : data];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration
defaultSessionConfiguration]]; [[session dataTaskWithRequest : request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                NSDictionary *JSON= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData :data options :NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];

               NSArray *alertArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"deletebookmark"];

                for (NSDictionary *alert in alertArray ){

                    if ([[alert objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"done"]) {
                        NSLog(@"done");
                         [spinner stopAnimating];
                   }
                    else{
                       NSLog(@"notDone"); 
                        [spinner stopAnimating];
                    }
                 }

            }]resume];

        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question properly, Make it more readable.

Comment: i'm new in stackoverflow i don't know how to do that . thankyou..

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Olaia thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath]; 

        if (!(cell == nil)) {
                        name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10]; name.text = [result objectAtIndex : indexPath.row]; 
                    } 
                    name.tag=indexPath.row; 
                    return cell; 
            }
```

In this datasource method, you have used a "if" condition, and due to your cell is reusable cell, so you have to use the else part too in this data source method.

Like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath]; 

if (!(cell == nil)) {
                    name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10]; name.text = [result objectAtIndex : indexPath.row]; 
                } 
               else{

                 name.tag=indexPath.row; 
               }

                return cell; 
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: still the last cell is deleting

Comment: I said, you have to use If Else part in cellforrowatindexpath datasource method, and i put an example, now you have to rectify it.

Comment: Here, result  count may be an array u are using, so you have to delete value from that array too, else after reloading it will be loaded in cell again.

Comment: that i'm doin in commitEditingStyle: method ....[result removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
[result removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableView reloadData];// comment this line above code

[spinner stopAnimating];

//After that you can add

[tableView reloadData]; // above stopanimating line.
```

Add this `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    }

    name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];

    name.text = [result objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];

    name.tag=indexPath.row;

    return cell;

 }
```

Comment: still the same problem i think problem is  in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: section. Thankyou

Comment: @RajeshDharani Please properly format your code, makes reading it easier! :)

Comment: @RajeshDharani why we taking this if(cell == nil).. please help i'm new in objective c

Comment: first time it always nill so why we taking this

Comment: @Mukul chauhan if cell is nil at that time we are allocated the UITableviewcell.  For Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3552369/5184217

Comment: @RajeshDharani  i tried all the way some time it will deleting the last cell some time randomly ... now i don't have any idea. ty.