# UIKit UITableViewCell Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

As part of my study to understand *UIKit* deeply and how its functions are implemented, I was reading that in the early years of iOS, *UITableView* loaded every cell in the table view, but after what they do was that now loads just cells that are visible.
So how could the *dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier:String)* be implemented?

```
class UITableView: UIScrollView {
    func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? {
    }
}
```

What I think is that there's an array that holds visible cells and that methods just filters according to the identifier. Something like this:

```
let cell = visibleCells.filter { $0.identifier == identifier }
return cell
```

But I want to know if there could be a better way to understand it and do it.

Comment: I think it's the opposite of what you're describing. dequeueReusableCell is looking at a collection of cells that aren't visible (i.e. can be blanked out and redrawn), and returning one of those and pulling it out of that pool. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552343/uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-theory

Answer (score 1):

There is a project "Chameleon" created 10 years ago which objective was to implement UIKit on macOS. The author done a lot of debug / reverse engineering to understand and mimics most of UIKit types. The code is accessible on [Github](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon) and UITableView implementation is [here](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UITableView.m)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in _reusableCells) {
        if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            UITableViewCell *strongCell = cell;

            // the above strongCell reference seems totally unnecessary, but without it ARC apparently
            // ends up releasing the cell when it's removed on this line even though we're referencing it
            // later in this method by way of the cell variable. I do not like this.
            [_reusableCells removeObject:cell];

            [strongCell prepareForReuse];
            return strongCell;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

There is also a reverse engineered version of UIKit from Microsoft but in c++ https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/tree/master/Frameworks/UIKit